# explode() is giving me blank values I am not expecting

Tags: php, explode

What I'm trying to do is separate a string based on how manys \n it has.. for example if I use this:

```
$string = "Hello\n stackoverflow";
$explode_insert = explode("\n", $string);
```

my expected result would be

1. Hello
2. ""
3. stackoverflow

---

if the `$string` is:

```
$string = "Hello \nstackoverflow\n\n how are you!"
```

my expected result would be:

1. Hello
2. ""
3. stackoverflow
4. ""
5. ""
6. how are you!

---

but instead if the explode gets "\n\n" it outputs this:

1. ""
2. ""
3. ""

theres an extra "" that I don't need, any ideas why is this happening?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PHP's [`explode`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) operates on the boundaries of the delimiter provided, and as such these are the expected results.

Here is an example:

```
\n\n
```

This yields 3 empty strings as there are 3 areas that are not "\n", before, between, and after; see here:

```
\n\n
^ ^ ^
```

Comment: You beet me to it hehe Well explained ;-)

Answer (score 0):

If the string you're exploding ends with the delimiter, the result array will always have an empty string at the end. If you want to avoid that, you can trim the delimiter off the end of the string before exploding it.

```
$result = explode("\n", rtrim($string, "\n"));
```

However, `rtrim` will remove *all* newlines from the end of the string, so if you use it with your `"\n\n"` example, the result array would have only one empty string rather than the two you're wanting. If you want to remove only the last newline, you can use `preg_replace` instead.

```
$result = explode("\n", preg_replace('/(.+)\n$/s', '$1', $string));
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran the following code:

```php
<?php
$string = "Hello\n stackoverflow";
$explode_insert = explode("\n", $string);
var_dump($explode_insert);
```

I got the following results:

```php
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  string(5) "Hello"
  [1]=>
  string(14) " stackoverflow"
}
```

The reason is that, when exploding a string, the string is split at the delimiter into an array, removing the delimiter. This means that it removes the "\n", and splits the string into two parts: "Hello" and " stackoverflow".

The second string results in:

```php
array(4) {
  [0]=>
  string(6) "Hello "
  [1]=>
  string(13) "stackoverflow"
  [2]=>
  string(0) ""
  [3]=>
  string(13) " how are you!"
}
```

This is because removing the two "\n\n" results in an empty string. This is where the second index in the array comes from.

Answer (score 0):

This will give you celar result of **Hello stackoverflow** with `str_replace`

```
$string = "Hello\n stackoverflow";
$explode_insert = str_replace('\n', '', $string);
echo $explode_insert;
```

Here are some more examples :

```
$string  = "piece1\n piece2\n piece3\n piece4\n piece5\n piece6\n";
$pieces = explode(" ", $string);
//Simple example
echo $pieces[0]; // piece1
echo $pieces[1]; // piece2

echo "<br>-----<br>";

var_dump($pieces);

echo "<br>-----<br>";
print_r($pieces);
```

Outputs :

```
piece1 piece2
-----
C:\wamp\www\a\test2.php:24:
array (size=6)
  0 => string 'piece1
' (length=7)
  1 => string 'piece2
' (length=7)
  2 => string 'piece3
' (length=7)
  3 => string 'piece4
' (length=7)
  4 => string 'piece5
' (length=7)
  5 => string 'piece6
' (length=7)

-----
Array ( [0] => piece1 [1] => piece2 [2] => piece3 [3] => piece4 [4] => piece5 [5] => piece6 )
```

More on php.net : https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php